# Concatanate Variable And Query MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is my working query:

```
collection.update({ _id: '124'}, {$addToSet: {'data.dropdowns.accessRoles': req.body.newItem}}, function(err, results) {
                   //
                });
```

I want to change data.dropdowns.accessRoles according to input string. Input variable is stored in req.body.listName. I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
{$addToSet: {'data.dropdowns.req.body.listName': req.body.newItem}}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: var setValue = {};
setValue['data.dropdowns' + req.body.listName] = 0;  I defined path like this. How do I use this in my query? {$addToSet: {setValue: req.body.newItem}} doesn't work. I don't know how to use $set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assembly your `$addToSet` object programmatically:

```
var addToSet = {};
addToSet['data.dropdowns.' + req.body.listName] = req.body.newItem;
collection.update({ _id: '124'}, {$addToSet: addToSet}, function(err) {...});
```